# OpenSSL in c++ error

Tags: c++, openssl

Here's the part of the server side code written in c++ and openssl, where the error seems to be occuring. The full code can be obtained from this link http://simplestcodings.blogspot.in/2010/08/secure-server-client-using-openssl-in-c.html

```
The error is
    In function ‘SSL_CTX* InitServerCTX()’:
serverssl.cpp:56:34: error: invalid conversion from ‘const SSL_METHOD* {aka const ssl_method_st*}’ to ‘SSL_METHOD* {aka ssl_method_st*}’ [-fpermissive]
 method = SSLv3_server_method();  /* create new server-method instance */
```

The code part is:

```
SSL_CTX* InitServerCTX(void)
{   SSL_METHOD *method;
     SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* load & register all cryptos, etc. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* load all error messages */
    method = SSLv3_server_method();  /* create new server-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* create new context from method */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}
```

Comment: so just change the declaration of method to include const.

Comment: Use `const SSL_METHOD *method;` instead of `SSL_METHOD *method;`

Comment: It worked now. I wasn't sure if we could use a const declaration. And are there any good tutorials for learning openssl?